# Swift2でRealmのデータベース名の指定と、データベースの保存場所を指定する方法

Tags: swift, realm

環境はXcode 7 bata5です。
使いたいのはOSXとiOSの両方です。

Realmのデータベース名の指定と、データベースの保存場所を指定する方法を教えていただけないでしょうか？

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Realmファイルをデフォルトの場所以外に保存するにはイニシャライザの`path`引数にファイルのパスを指定します。引数で指定されたパスにファイルが作られます。

パスにはファイル名も含まれていますので、名前を変える場合も同様になります。

このAPIを使うと複数のRealmファイルを使用することもできます。

下記はドキュメントディレクトリに`data.realm`という名前でRealmファイルを作成する例です。

```
let paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.DocumentDirectory, .UserDomainMask, true)
let realmPath = (paths[0] as NSString).stringByAppendingPathComponent("data.realm")

do {
    let realm = try Realm(path: realmPath)

    realm.write {
        // ...
    }
} catch {
    // Error handling...
}
```

Comment: ありがとうございます。別にもう一つ質問をしましたので、よろしくお願いいたします。